# tensorflow mnist neural network model low accuracy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am getting only 9 percent accuracy for this basic mnist model.

Can anyone help me to understand what am I doing wrong here?

```
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (60000, 784))
x_test  = np.reshape(x_test, (10000, 784))
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 10))
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((784, 10)))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((10)))
y_hat = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, w) + b)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum((y * tf.log(y_hat)), axis=1))
training_gd = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.05).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.initializers.global_variables().run()

for _ in range(10000):
    indices = np.random.randint(0, len(x_train), 100)
    batch_xs, batch_ys =  x_train[indices], y_train[indices]
    sess.run(training_gd, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_hat, axis=1), tf.argmax(y, axis=1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test, y: y_test}))
0.098
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing cross entropy with:

```py
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum((y * tf.log(y_hat)), axis=1))
```

is numerically unstable.

You can normalize images between 0 and 1.

```py
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (60000, 784)) / 255.0
x_test  = np.reshape(x_test, (10000, 784)) / 255.0
```

Or compute cross entropy with TensorFlow API

```py
logits = tf.matmul(x, w) + b
y_hat = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y)
```

Comment: Thank you but can you explain a bit on why it's considered unstable?

Comment: Numerical instability happens when the logits from the network output are large and we estimate the exp() of large numbers to get softmax output. Image pixel values are between 0 and 255 so we divide by 255 to get images from 0 and 1.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask can you also explain this line `accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))`? Here as you know `correct_prediction` will be an array of o's and 1's

Comment: Accuracy is is the ratio of number of correct predictions to the total number of input samples. Average is the sum of array elements divided by the number of elements. We sum the `correct_prediction` array elements so we get the number of correct predictions (because 1 is a correct prediction) and we divide by the total number of input elements so we get the total number of input samples.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much.